# Lost huge internal memory while debugging application on device

Tags: internal-storage

I started developing Android apps recently. For debugging purpose I used my device. Debugs and all went good but lately I realised that 32MB of my internal memory is missing.

I have gone through all the applications, cleared caches but nothing helped.

Does anyone have any idea as to how should I get back the 32 MB's of Space on my Device.

Device: **HTC Desire**
Android Platform: **2.3.3**

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, as devices are setup differently -- but the word "debugging" suggests it:

If you are rooted, check whether the directory `/data/tombstones` exists. If so, there might be some "tombstones" inside. Being root, you can delete them (they are owned by `system`, and give no permissions whatsoever to other users).

**Explanation: Tombstones**

Tombstones are what the dead are covered with, and so it is here. On Linux/Unix known as "core dumps", this is what some apps leave behind when crashed to death: the process' memory dump for analysis by the developer. Only few applications throw tombstones, I guess they have to be explicitly enabled by the developer -- which might happen implicitly when toggling some debug flags.

Up to now, I didn't discover tombstones of that size (all I've seen was between ~30kB and ~250MB), but that doesn't mean they cannot be bigger...

Comment: Handy Note: 32 megs is between 30k and 250meg! So you have seen tombstones of that size! :)

Comment: What did I write there? That should have been 2.5MB max...